# PHPMailer's infamous SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, google-apps

I'm trying to get PHPMailer working using a Google Apps SMTP server. I've tried:

1. Uncommenting openssl in php.ini
2. Telneting Google's server on port 465 (success)
3. Telneting my webserver on port 465 (success)
4. Telnetting Google's server from my server (success)
5. Checking DNS SPF/MX records (and sanitizing to IPv4)
6. tls on port 587
7. webhost confirms they allow outbound SMTP traffic
8. google captcha's unlock trick
9. Reading everything I could find on StackOverflow (solutions covered the above)

Can someone provide a solution to the timed out connection?

Here's my code:

```
require_once ( 'class.phpmailer.php' ); // Add the path as appropriate
$Mail = new PHPMailer();
$Mail->IsSMTP(); // Use SMTP
$Mail->Host        = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Sets SMTP server
$Mail->SMTPDebug   = 1; // 2 to enable SMTP debug information
$Mail->SMTPAuth    = TRUE; // enable SMTP authentication
$Mail->SMTPSecure  = "ssl"; //Secure conection
$Mail->Port        = 465; // set the SMTP port
$Mail->Username    = 'account@googleappsaddress.com'; // SMTP account username
$Mail->Password    = 'mypassword'; // SMTP account password
$Mail->Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
$Mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
$Mail->Encoding    = '8bit';
$Mail->Subject     = 'Test Email Using Gmail';
$Mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
$Mail->From        = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$Mail->FromName    = 'GMail Test';
$Mail->WordWrap    = 900; // RFC 2822 Compliant for Max 998 characters per line

$Mail->AddAddress( $to ); // To:
$Mail->isHTML( TRUE );
$Mail->Body    = $body;
$Mail->AltBody = $MessageTEXT;
$Mail->Send();
$Mail->SmtpClose();

if(!$Mail->Send()) {
    $error = 'Mail error: '.$Mail->ErrorInfo; 
    echo($error);
    return false;
} else {
    $error = 'Message sent!';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: did you confirm with the webhost that they allow port 465? "smtp" is port 25. port 465 is "ssmtp" - smtp over ssl, and may be blocked because it is a different protocol

Comment: @MarcB, yes. I also was successful in traffic to another server thru 465.

Comment: check that there's no application-level firewall running on the server. if telneting->google from the command line works but not from the webserver, then something could be blocking the webserver from reading out in that way.

Comment: I'm able to telnet from my webserver (via ssh) to gmail's SMTP server on port 465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was a victim of coincidence. When I ssh'ed to my server and telneted to Gmail, it was open - however, due to the openssl not being uncommented, I suspect that is why it initially failed.

However, while attempting to get it working, the host firewall blacklisted Gmail. They're currently looking into why, but the short answer is it is white-listed and working.